Chrome mobile browser background-position image bug?
I've set up several divs using a class of .polaroid to display in "photo" style border that uses a single sprite background image (made up of a grid of many 100x100px images).
.polaroid {
background:url("../images/sprite.jpg") no-repeat;color:transparent;
    margin:10px 15px 5px 0;
outline: 5px solid #EBEBEB;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-size: cover;
display: block;
float:left;
-webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
-moz-transition: all .15s linear;
transition: all .15s linear;    
}

A CSS rule positions the background image.
.pool{background-position:-300px 0px;}
.kayaks{background-position:-400px 0px;}
.woman{background-position:-3400px 0px;}
.man{background-position:-3500px 0px;}

It works perfectly across all browsers (including Chrome on laptop) EXCEPT for Google Chrome on Android. Several images are off by about 5px or so. The odd thing is that many are correctly positioned, but some are not.
In the Chrome mobile screenshot you can see the images of the pool and kayak are correct, the picture of the woman and man are not positioned correctly.

To view the "correct" website, it is at this URL (scroll to the bottom of the page): https://www.taupoaccommodation.co/index.php
Any thoughts or help greatly appreciated!
Seems to work on every browser except Google Chrome running version 124.0.6367.113 (Android mobile)

Finally found the solution, still not sure why Chrome (mobile does this) but changing the sprite background-size from cover to % worked
.polaroid {
background:url("../images/sprite.jpg") no-repeat;color:transparent; 
background-size: 4300% 100%;/*grid is 43 images in a single row  images @200px grid fixed Chrome issue with offset bg images from sprite*/
width:100px;
height:100px;

}
...fixed the problem. BTW, I use images at 200x200px each in a "polaroid" style div sized at 100px x 100px to achieve a good retina-quality display. Hope this helps someone else.
Greg
